# How to change an attribute of a text element inside a svg?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I have this SVG to achieve a text gradient. How can I change the font-size attribute using jQuery?

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="600" height="40" class="detail_val_svg">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#4FB6D7;stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-coloR:#325FF3;stop-opacity:1" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <text fill="url(#grad1)" font-size="34" font-family="Helvetica" x="0" y="28">
    MY TEXT HERE
  </text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('svg text').css('font-size', 8);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="600" height="40" class="detail_val_svg">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#4FB6D7;stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-coloR:#325FF3;stop-opacity:1" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <text fill="url(#grad1)" font-size="34" font-family="Helvetica" x="0" y="28">
    MY TEXT HERE
  </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: I don't know why you have been downvoted. This worked for me. And I realised I don't need javascript for my mediaqueries, I can use plain old css... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `attr` property as a setter.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('svg text').attr('font-size', 12);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vraxwppz/